# STM32F4 - External input source is not detected in GPIO.pulldown mode

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, gpio

I am currently working on a project that involves an `STM32 F4 Discovery board` where I am trying to use an external input source as the input to the `GPIO` pin. The external input source is a power supply set to 3.3V. The pins are set to mode `GPIO_PULLDOWN` such that the input is grounded when no particular value is assigned. However, I am unable to change the input value once it is grounded. When I set the power supply to give 3.3V to the input pin, it still stays grounded. But when I connect a 3.3V pin on the board to the input pin, it gets 3.3V as input. I have noticed one thing, which I find a bit strange: when I use a multimeter to measure the input pin, the multimeter measures 3.3V on the input pin when I use `GND` from the power supply and the `VCC` from the input pin. But when I use the `GND` pin from microcontroller and `VCC` from the input pin, it outputs 0V.

Any idea how I can solve this? I am quite fresh on this topic, so all advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The ground on the power supply is isolated, thus I needed to connect the ground on power supply with the microcontroller.